# How can a single for loop iterate over multiple arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

In this case I'm using two parallel arrays (`cost[]` and `scores[]`) both of these with data on them that is parallel to each other.

This code is correct as am copying it from the book I'm using. What i don't get is how can this for loop work for the costs array. I get we are passing both arrays as parameters in the function but in the for loop there is only `scores.length`, so shouldn't be another loop for `cost.lenght`?

```
function getMostCostEffectiveSolution(scores, costs, highScore)  
    var cost = 100;  
    var index;  

    for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {  
        if (scores[i] == highScore) {  
            if(cost > cost[i]) {
                index = i;  
                cost = cost[i];  
            }
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: It looks like the code assumes both costs and scores have the same length. If they both have the same length you only need to use one of their lengths. Note you have a typo you are using `cost[i]` when it probably should be `costs[i]`

Comment: If they are parallel arrays, aren't their lengths the same?

Comment: I think in this case both the array lengths are same.

Comment: Just rephrasing what @PatrickEvans said. You can use the same index "i" for both arrays because both arrays have the same length and the value at index i of cost array is related to the value at index i of scores array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array
>
> In computing, a group of parallel arrays is a data structure for
>   representing arrays of records. It keeps a separate, homogeneous array
>   for each field of the record, **each having the same number of elements**

If they both are truly parallel than both arrays are going to be the same length.

So `scores.length == costs.length`. You only need to use one for the loop condition, and use the same index variable to access both arrays.

Example

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [4,5,6];

for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    console.log(a[i] +"  "+ b[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

Using b's length

```
for(var i=0; i<b.length; i++){
    console.log(a[i] +"  "+ b[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

Comment: Just an idea, but you could wrap the for loop in `if ( a.length == b.length ) { for...}`